# How to refine some specific surfaces in Avizo?

Tags: mesh, abaqus, meshlab, tomography-reconstruction

I m using Avizo to generate a mesh of my microstructure obtained from CT scan in order to launch computations in Abaqus. I can generate interesting surfaces meshes, nonetheless outside mesh is too fine (you can see figure with this question). I am trying to create a surface path to have a coarser mesh in outside mesh but it doesnt work. When I remesh my model all is modified...
How can i generate sub-surfaces in order to specificy special mesh conditions?
Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: But the outside mesh is just the boundary of the inside mesh no? So it must have the same resolution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your question is how can I break my mesh into separate components - perform some work on those components and then put them back together.

There is a tool to select connected components in a region in the toolbar area at the top of the meshlab window which you can use to select any triangle on the outside boundary and it will grab all the connected parts of the mesh. Then with "Filters->Mesh Layer->Move Selected Faces to Another Layer" you can separate the selected part of the mesh into a new layer. Alternatively you can use right click on the layer and select split in connected components. On this new layer you can perform simplification filters such as clustering decimation.

Once you have completed the simplification to your satisfaction, make visible the layers that you want to merge back together and use the filter "Filters->Mesh Layer->Flatten Visible Layers" to put them back together.